# How can I get the name of a variable in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

How can I get the name of a variable in SQL? something like C# `nameof(variable)`

In a SQL stored procedure, I handle a variable, `@MetaData`, which is a string repressing a JSON with a predefined structure:

```
{
  'Somekey1': 'Somevalue1',
  'Somekey2': 'Somevalue2'
}
```

Within the stored procedure, I check whether `Somekey1` exists, and perform actions accordingly:

```
declare @existingSomekey1 VARCHAR(100) = (select [value]
from openjson(@Metadate) where [key] = 'Somevalue1')
```

Later, I do actions like:

```
set @Somekey1 = 'Some new value 1'
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@Metadata, '$.Somekey1', @Somekey1)
```

So in the `JSON_MODIFY` command, if I provide the wrong path (which is the same as the variable name), it will create a different property altogether, which is wrong.
What's the best practice here to avoid typos in providing that path? which would lead to errors and exceptions...

Comment: There is no such feature. If you typo the name of the variable/parameter to one that doesn't exist the batch won't compile, so address the error then. This smells like an [XY problem](//xyproblem.info) to me, if o am honest.

Comment: The issue isn't in compilation, but rather that the variable's name is the same as the property name inside the JSON. so in the JSON_MODIFY command, if I provide the wrong path, it will create a different property altogether.

Comment: It would be useful here, if I understand the limited usecase of `nameof()` in C# correctly where you want compilation to fail if you mistype the `'$.SomeKey1'` json path, but I agree with Larnu that there is no feature like this in sql procs. You'll just have to be careful.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question correctly, the goal is to prevent adding entry for non-existing path and this could be achieved by adding `strict`:

```
DECLARE @Metadata NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"Somekey1": "Somevalue1",
                                    "Somekey2": "Somevalue2"}'
       ,@Somekey1 NVARCHAR(100) = 'Some new value 1';

SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@Metadata, '$.Somekey3', @Somekey1);
```

Output:

```
{ "Somekey1": "Somevalue1",
  "Somekey2": "Somevalue2",
  "Somekey3":"Some new value 1"}
```

Using `strict`:

```
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@Metadata, 'strict $.Somekey3', @Somekey1)
```

Output:

> Property cannot be found on the specified JSON path.

**[db<>fiddle live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ssnt9Twg)**

Comment: A good mitigation/way around.

Comment: This is better than "query first".  Depending on what code can change, and what the impact of having extra paths is... you could also write an OPENJSON clause that is reformatted via FOR JSON, effectively stripping out unwanted artifacts. At some point though, "I provide the wrong path" is understandable in that "If I write the code wrong, it doesn't behave as expected".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this adds to the discussion, but ...

In 2016, the JSON `key` has to be a `literal`.   However, in 2017+ the `key` can be an expression

**Example**

```
DECLARE @Metadata NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{
  "Somekey1": "Somevalue1",
  "Somekey2": "Somevalue2"
}'

Declare @MyKey varchar(100),@MyVal varchar(100)

Select @MyKey = [key]
      ,@MyVal = [Value]
 From  OpenJson(@Metadata)
 Where [Key]='Somekey2'

Set @MyVal = 'This is a NEW Value';

SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@Metadata, '$.'+@MyKey, @MyVal)
```

**Results**

```
{
  "Somekey1": "Somevalue1", 
  "Somekey2": "This is a NEW Value" 
}
```